# ory dockertest and kafka from confluentinc

Tags: docker, go, apache-kafka

i can't figure out how properly spin out dockertest with zookeeper and kafka from confluentinc.
my goal is to have a test instance of ZooKeeper and Kafka running on ports that do not interfere with the production Kafka instances. additionally, i would like to configure it so that different hosts can be used, not just 'localhost'.
currently, my code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ory/dockertest/v3"
    "github.com/ory/dockertest/v3/docker"
    "time"
)

const namePrefix = "test_container"

var kafkaPort string //used in tests

func main() {
    containers, err := StartDockerContainers()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    containers.Stop()
}

type KafkaDockerTest struct {
    pool      *dockertest.Pool
    network   *docker.Network
    zookeeper *dockertest.Resource
    kafka     *dockertest.Resource
}

func StartDockerContainers() (*KafkaDockerTest, error) {

    pool, err := dockertest.NewPool("")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not connect to docker: %w", err)
    }

    err = pool.Client.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not connect to docker: %w", err)
    }

    timestampAssignation := time.Now().UnixNano()

    network, err := pool.Client.CreateNetwork(docker.CreateNetworkOptions{Name: fmt.Sprintf("zookeeper_kafka_network_%d", timestampAssignation)})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not create a network to zookeeper and kafka: %w", err)
    }

    zookeeperOptions := &dockertest.RunOptions{
        Name:       fmt.Sprintf("%s-zookeeper-%d", namePrefix, timestampAssignation),
        Repository: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper",
        NetworkID:  network.ID,
        Tag:        "latest",
        Hostname:   "zookeeper",
        Env: []string{
            "ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181",
        },
    }
    zookeeperResource, err := pool.RunWithOptions(zookeeperOptions, func(config *docker.HostConfig) {
        // set AutoRemove to true so that stopped container goes away by itself
        config.AutoRemove = false //for debug
        config.RestartPolicy = docker.RestartPolicy{
            Name: "no",
        }
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not start zookeeper: %s", err)
    }

    //todo ping - pool.Retry(func() error {}

    kafkaOptions := &dockertest.RunOptions{
        Name:       fmt.Sprintf("%s-kafka-%d", namePrefix, timestampAssignation),
        Repository: "confluentinc/cp-kafka",
        Tag:        "latest",
        Hostname:   "kafka",
        NetworkID:  network.ID,
        Env: []string{  
            "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9093",
            "KAFKA_LISTENERS=INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093",

            "KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1",
            "KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1",
            "KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181",
            "KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INSIDE",

            "KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT",
        },
        PortBindings: map[docker.Port][]docker.PortBinding{
            "9093/tcp": {{HostIP: "localhost", HostPort: "9093/tcp"}},
        },
        ExposedPorts: []string{"9093/tcp"},
    }

    kafkaResource, err := pool.RunWithOptions(kafkaOptions, func(config *docker.HostConfig) {
        // set AutoRemove to true so that stopped container goes away by itself
        config.AutoRemove = false
        config.RestartPolicy = docker.RestartPolicy{
            Name: "no",
        }
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not start kafka: %s", err)
    }

    //todo ping - pool.Retry(func() error {}

    kafkaPort = kafkaResource.GetPort("9093/tcp")

    return &KafkaDockerTest{
        pool:      pool,
        network:   network,
        zookeeper: zookeeperResource,
        kafka:     kafkaResource,
    }, nil
}

func (kdt *KafkaDockerTest) Stop() error {
    if kdt == nil || kdt.zookeeper == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not stop zookeeper container")
    }

    if err := kdt.pool.Purge(kdt.zookeeper); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not purge resource %v :%s", kdt.zookeeper, err)
    }

    if kdt == nil || kdt.kafka == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not stop kafka container")
    }

    if err := kdt.pool.Purge(kdt.kafka); err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("could not purge resource %v :%s", kdt.kafka, err)
    }

    if err := kdt.pool.Client.RemoveNetwork(kdt.network.ID); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not remove network %s :%s", kdt.network.ID, err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

In the best case scenario, I receive information that:

```
dial tcp: lookup kafka: no such host
```

Comment: What's actually returning the error? Where is your test code? Your config looks fine (though, I suggest not using latest image tag and zookeeper isn't necessary). You need to use localhost to connect to a locally running docker instance... And if that's not running on an existing broker, how would that affect production?